# Randomization test for binary value in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset with Yes No values for Cancer. Below an example of the dataset

```
set.seed(42)
cancer <- sample(c("yes", "no"), 200, replace=TRUE) 
agegroup <- sample(c("35-39", "40-44", "45-49"), 200, replace=TRUE)  
agefirstchild <- sample(c("Age < 30", "Age 30 or greater", "nullipareous"), 200, replace=TRUE) 
dat <- data.frame(cancer, agegroup, agefirstchild)
```

From this dataset I would like to subtract 5000 samples. Each sample contains 10% of the dataset. An then take the proportion of the yes value of Cancer of each sample. And from the 5000 values I would like to make a histogram of the 5000 proportion-values from Cancer Yes, as well as get a summary with mean, median, quartiles, and standard deviation of this histogram.

This code below, calculates the proportion. But now I need it from 10% of the dataset, 5000 times and in a histogram with summary

```
resample <- sample(dat, replace = TRUE)
proportion <- prop.table(table(resample$Cancer))
```

I can find few examples of how to do this with numeric values but not with binary values. But how can I perform such a test with binary values?

Comment: riskwoinvasivetrain is the name of my dataset. From my dataset with 280000 records, I would like to generate 5000 samples (10% of the dataset)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the dataset `dat` you propose above, you can loop 5000 times, keeping the proportion of `cancer=="yes"` each time, like so:

```
samplesize <- nrow(dat)*0.10
result_vec <- vector(length=samplesize)
for(i in 1:5000) {
    rows_to_keep <- sample(1:nrow(dat), size=samplesize, replace=F)
    result_vec[i] <- mean(dat$cancer[rows_to_keep] == "yes")
}

hist(result_vec)
```

The "trick" here with binary variables is to first create a vector of 1's and 0's for when a condition is true/false, and then to take the mean of that vector. This gives you the percentage of times the condition is true.

If you would like to calculate other quantities of interest (e.g., standard deviation of the 5000 proportions), you can do:

```
sd(result_vec)
```

Comment: It works thanks! I will change "riskwoinvasivetrain" to "dat" in my text above. Thanks for the clear explanation.